# pandas assert_frame_equal fails to compare two identical dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, testing

I am trying to use `assert_frame_equal` for tests by comparing the function return dataframe to a dataframe read from a csv file. The csv file was created from the dataframe that this function returns:

```
results = my_fun()
results.to_csv("test.csv", mode="w", sep="\t", index=False)
```

Therefore, I assume they should be identical.
Now, in the test I have the following code.

```
results = my_fun()
test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep="\t", header="infer", index_col=False, encoding="utf-8")
assert_frame_equal(results.reset_index(drop=True), test_df.reset_index(drop=True), check_column_type=False, check_dtype=False)
```

What I get is the following exception:

```
E   AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="document_id") are different
E
E   DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="document_id") values are different (100.0 %)
E   [left]:  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
E   [right]: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

I am scratching my head. What is the actual difference here?
If I print `results["document_id"]` and `test_df["document_id"]` I get:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
Name: document_id, dtype: object <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
Name: document_id, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Maybe one has strings in the index and one has integers.

Comment: I fixed it with `pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep="\t", header="infer", index_col=False, encoding="utf-8", dtype=str)`.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you compare in a different way?  E.g.,

```
results['document_id'] == test_df['document_id']
```

UPDATE: Question 2:  what happens for:

```
results['document_id'].reset_index(drop=True) == \
test_df['document_id'].reset_index(drop=True)

# and for
results.index == test_df.index
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`.

Comment: I found the reason. `print(results["document_id"].values, test_df["document_id"].values)` gives: `['1' '1' '1' '2' '2' '2' '2' '2'] [1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]`. Strange, why pandas reports string as an object which tells nothing to you.